# OpenIddict can't Use Cosmos as Database Because of ETag Concurrency is Supported

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-cosmosdb, openiddict

I'm trying to use Azure Cosmos DB as my OpenIddict DB:

```
   options.UseCosmos(...) in Startup.cs
```

and am getting the following exception

```
The entity type 'CustomOpenIdApplication' has property 'ConcurrencyToken' as its concurrency token, but only '_etag' is supported. Consider using 'EntityTypeBuilder.UseETagConcurrency'.'
```

I've tried putting the following in my DBContext but same problem occurs.

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
             modelBuilder.Entity<CustomOpenIdApplication>().Property(b => b.ConcurrencyToken)
                .IsETagConcurrency();}
```

How to solve this as it seems that OpenIddict was designed to use ConcurrencyToken and not Etag  for concurrency, but the exception clearly says that only Etag concurrency is supported.

Note that if I use sqlserver as my DB then I don't have any issues.

Comment: Please include links to the docs or guide you're following? To my knowledge OpenIddict has no explicit support for CosmosDB (although you can implement your own stores and it works just fine)

Comment: He wants to use EF Core on top of Cosmos DB

Comment: ever manager to make this work ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and managed to get this working by using `ETagConcurrency` for the Entity in the `OnModelCreating` override like this:

`modelBuilder.Entity<CustomOpenIdApplication>().UseETagConcurrency();`